# Help with linear algebra in fast Toeplitz inversion paper

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I am trying to work through the 2017 paper [A new Toeplitz inversion formula, stability analysis and the value](https://www.isr-publications.com/jnsa/3673/download-a-new-toeplitz-inversion-formula-stability-analysis-and-the-value) by Yanpeng Zhenga, Zunwei Fub, and Sugoog Shona.

In this paper the authors present a fast $O(n log(n))$ Toeplitz inversion formula. However, there are some details that seem to be lacking for those wishing to replicate the algorithm.

Here is the relevant part of the paper:

$\newcommand\iddots{\mathinner{
  \kern1mu\raise1pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise4pt{.}
  \kern2mu\raise7pt{\Rule{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}.}
  \kern1mu
}}$

Let $ T=(a_{i-j=1}^{n}) $ be an $n \times n$ Toeplitz matrix, then it satisfies the formula:

$$
\Xi T - T\Xi = ve_n^T - e_1v^TJ
$$

where

$$
\Xi = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &&& -1 \\ 1 & \ddots && \\ & \ddots & \ddots & \\ && 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, J = \begin{pmatrix} &&& 1 \\ && 1 & \\ & \iddots && \\ 1 &&& \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
e_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, e_n = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, v = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ a_{1-n} + a_1 \\ \vdots \\ a_{-2} + a_{n - 2} \\ a_{-1} + a_{n - 1}  \end{pmatrix}.
$$

$$
$$

The paper implies there is a solution to $Tx = v, Ty = e_1$ without inverting the matrix $T$. I believe using $T^{-1}$ to solve $Tx = v, Ty = e_1$ would defeat the point of the paper.

My question is: **Can anyone explain to me how $x$ and $y$ might be solved using the given equations without inverting $T$?**

Obviously $Tx = v, Ty = e_1$ could be solved for $x, y$ using a Toeplitz solver or by direct inversion of $T$. But, again this would seem to invalidate the point of the paper. My guess is that combining and rearranging $\Xi T - T\Xi = ve_n^T - e_1v^TJ$ and $Tx = v, Ty = e_1$ in some way will provide expressions for $x, y$ that do not require $T^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

After some research it looks like the special forms of $v, e_1, e_n$ allow $Tx=v,Ty=e_1$ can be solved using Padé tables. For instance, the 1985 paper *A New Algorithm for Solving Toeplitz Systems of Equations* by Frank de Hoog illustrates the solution.

I believe the 2017 paper could be incorrect in its assertion of $O(nlog(n))$ and it is in fact $O(nlog^2(n))$ due to the complexity of the Padé table based subproblems.